# Open image from an API in a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a problem. I have a project of an image gallery by getting the images from the Unsplash API. I have them displayed by bootstrap cards generated through javascript. I want to setup a download button on the card footer so that when clicked, the image opens in a new tab.

```
//this is how I get the images from the API

function pedir_imagens(pageNumber) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.unsplash.com/photos?&page=' + pageNumber + '&per_page=24&order_by=latest&client_id=dd4e1cb73ca3a1036d4e98d26f72a439141dc17039e1ae79b7bc2a23f3488578',
        type: "get",
        async: true,
        success: function (data, status, response) {
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                adicionarImagem(data[i]);
            }
         }
    })
}

//this is how I add the images to the page

function adicionarImagem(imagem) {
    var card_image_div = $("<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 card-margin'></div>");
    var card_div = $("<div class='card p-0'></div>");
    var img_cartaz = imagem["urls"]["raw"] + "&fit=crop&w=500&h=500";
    var img = $("<img class='card-img-top'>");
    img.attr('src', img_cartaz);
    var card_title = $("<div class='card-body'></div>");
    var card_title_text = $("<h4 class='card-title text-left'></h4>");
    card_title_text.text(imagem["user"]["name"]);
    card_title.append(card_title_text);


    var card_text = $("<h5 class='card-title text-left'></h5>");
    card_text.text(imagem["description"]);
    card_title.append(card_text);

    var dl_icon = $("<button id=imgID class='btn btn-default' onclick='window.open(imagem['urls']['raw']);'><i class='fas fa-download' align='right'></i></button > ")
    var card_footer = $("<div class='card-footer'></div>");
    card_footer.append(dl_icon);

    card_div.append(img);
    card_div.append(card_title);
    card_div.append(card_footer);
    card_image_div.append(card_div);

    $('#images_container').append(card_image_div);
}
```

Comment: Don't use inline `onclick` code. You have single quotes inside an `onclick` attribute delimited by single quotes. Just use jQuery: `dl_icon.click(function() { window.open(imagem.urls.raw); });`

Comment: Here's how to build HTML with jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/qh8k2jr9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are almost there

```
var dl_icon = $("<button id=imgID class='btn btn-default'><i class='fas fa-download' align='right'></i></button > ")

dl_icon.click(function(){
    window.open(imagem['urls']['raw']);
});
```

1. first of all there is no point using inline events `onclick=` if you generate html using JS
2. nothing was passed to argument in onclick, the html you generated was

> onclick='window.open(imagem['urls']['raw']);'

instead

> onclick='window.open("http://proper.url/link-to-image.jpg");'

this would work

```
var dl_icon = $("<button id=imgID class='btn btn-default' onclick='window.open(\"" + imagem['urls']['raw']) + "\"'><i class='fas fa-download' align='right'></i></button > ")
```

but as I said you dynamically create DOM elements, there is no point to use `onclick="..."` attributes

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple, you can even do it without JS.

Just use an `a` tag and set the target to 'new' and the url to be that of the image.

E.G.

`<a href="IMG_URL" target="new" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a>`

In your JS above, you would just pop the tag in the appropriate place and voila.